# Crystal Reports showing blank images

Tags: c#, asp.net, image, crystal-reports, report

I have developed crystal reports on my development machine and everything is working fine.
My development machine configuration is :

- Windows 7 64 bit
- IIS 7.0  Crystal Reports 13 (13.0.2000.0)
- Visual
  Studio 2010 (framework 4.0)
- Built Crystal reports with targeting
  framework 2.0

But, when i deployed the same application on my deployment server, blank image is displaying on crystal reports.

Deployment Server Config :

- Windows 2008 R2 64 bit
- Crystal Reports 10 (10.2.3600.0)
- Visual Studio 2010 (framework 4.0)
- Built Crystal reports with targeting framework 2.0

When I check the URL of the image on both development & deployment machines, the paths are like this.

- Development : **/EnterpriseASP/reports/COSIS**/CrystalImageHandler.aspxdynamicimage=cr_tmp_image_xxxxxxxxx.png
- Deployment:
  **/EnterpriseASP**/CrystalImageHandler.aspxdynamicimage=cr_tmp_image_xxxxxxxx.png

Note:

- The image here is dynamically generated using OLEDB object.
- Enterprise Asp is my root folder of the project

Comment: Have you checked the permissions on the image file?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the permissions on the file location are not set to allow the internet user access.

Comment: But, as I mentioned in the above question, Crystal Report Viewer is locate in EnterpriseASP/reports/COSIS directory and the CrystalImageHandler.aspx is also located under same directory in my local machine. But on server, CrystalImageHandler.aspx is showing under EnterpriseASP directory. Any reasons for this?